# How to interpret D-Efficiency in Experimental Design in R OptFederov?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, mixed-model, conjoint-analysis

I created an orthogonal design in R using AlgDesign package. I got 14 profiles and some output: D =0.2519353; A = 5.462121; Ge = 0.748; Dea = 0.714.

How to interpret D , A , Ge and Dea? Also, In regression like we have r square, which value should we be looking for D-Efficiency and how much it should be in order for this design to be usable in a choice based conjoint/Discrete choice model experiment as alternatives? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found answer myself. Design efficiency is judged by Ge. It should be 1 or close to 1. Below links have some explanation and i referred the book "Design and Analysis of Experiments with R". Thought this might be useful for those who are looking for answer.

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-October/143217.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395486/error-in-hierarchical-bayesn-in-r-bayesn-package

Comment: Hi, could you please have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/581702/meaning-of-ge-in-optfederov-in-r-or-how-to-value-a-design ?