# Meaning of Ge in optFederov() in R or how to value a design

Tags: r, experiment-design

Refering to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137695/how-to-interpret-d-efficiency-in-experimental-design-in-r-optfederov) I evaluate the function [optfedorov](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AlgDesign/versions/1.2.1/topics/optFederov) by looking at the `Ge` value. When I use this function without specifying any value:

```
cand.list = expand.grid(T = c("5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40"),
                        rH = c("10", "40", "70"))
set.seed(70)
optFederov( ~ ., data = cand.list)
```

I receive this design:

```
$D
[1] 0.1244044

$A
[1] 15.60938

$Ge
[1] 0.41

$Dea
[1] 0.238

$design
    T rH
4  20 10
5  25 10
6  30 10
7  35 10
8  40 10
9   5 40
10 10 40
12 20 40
13 25 40
17  5 70
18 10 70
19 15 70
22 30 70
23 35 70
24 40 70

$rows
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 13 17 18 19 22 23 24
```

which provides a `Ge` value of `0.41` which is allegedly not so good. Shall I tune the design automatically to reach `Ge` (e.g. I achieve this by using a full factorial design which I could set up on my own without the need for any DoE..) or does `Ge` provide a different meaning?

The [description](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AlgDesign/versions/1.2.1/topics/optFederov) tells:

> **Ge**   The minimax normalized variance over $ X $, expressed as an efficiency
> with respect to the optimal approximate theory design. It is defined
> as $ k/max(d) $, where $ max(d) $ is the maximum normalized variance
> over $ X $ -- i.e. the max of $ x'(M_i)x $, over all rows $x' $of $ X $.

Comment: To the close-voter: This question is to me clearly **clearly on-topic**, as it need statistical expertise to answer. You will **NOT** find a good answer only by reading the documentation of *optFederov*, for instance. For more discussion see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5985/closing-software-questions

Comment: Hard to interpret Ge. The only explanation I found when I was working on experimental design was that if it's 1, then design is optimal. So the only way I got from this explanation was that somehow adjust the design so that we get Ge as 1. I am not sure how it is going to work for you. Best wishes!!

Comment: @StatguyUser Thank you! But I'm not wrong when not specifying anything that the resulting design should be optimal, though, or?

Comment: Does anyone know something I can read up to get a better understanding, especially towards evaluating such designs?

Comment: Ge is comparing with an impossibility, the approximate (or continuous) design, which is not realizable. Especially when n is small, don't take Ge to seriously. If its close to 1, good, if not ? does not say much